# Opacity and colour transitions for backgrounds?

Tags: html, css, transition, display

I'm working on a project involving a header that appears on scroll which has panels which change opacity and slightly colour when you hover over them but couldn't get the transition to work in Chrome or Firefox.

```css
.revundhov:hover {
  background-color: rgba(238, 236, 236, 0.4);
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .3s;
  -o-transition: background-color .3s;
}

.revundhov {
  background-color: rgba(25, 31, 40, 0.9);
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s;
  -o-transition: background-color .2s;
}
```

```html
<body style='background-color: blue;'>


  <div id='transhead' style='box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9); height: 100px; max-height: 100vh; overflow: hidden; position: fixed; top:0; left: 0; z-index: 10000;  width: 100%; '>
    <a href='/dxlphin/'>
      <div style='width: 100vw; height: 100%;  display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content:left'>
        <div class='revundhov' style='background-color: rgba(238, 236, 236, 0.9); width: 5vw; height: 100%;'>HOME</div>
        <div class='revundhov' style='background-color: rgba(238, 236, 236, 0.9); width: 30vw; height: 100%;'>Products</div>
        <div class='revundhov' style='background-color: rgba(238, 236, 236, 0.9); width: 30vw; height: 100%;'>Ranges</div>
        <div class='revundhov' style='background-color: rgba(238, 236, 236, 0.9); width: 30vw; height: 100%;'>Featured</div>
        <div class='revundhov' style='background-color: rgba(238, 236, 236, 0.9); width: 5vw; height: 100%;'>CART</div>
      </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Any suggestions as to what's wrong would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If any of the answers helped you, you should check it as the answer. This will help other users as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use inline style. I have removed the inline background color and it works just fine.

```css
.revundhov:hover {
  background-color: rgba(238, 236, 236, 0.4);
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .3s;
  -o-transition: background-color .3s;
}

.revundhov {
  background-color: rgba(25, 31, 40, 0.9);
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s;
  -o-transition: background-color .2s;
}
```

```html
<body style='background-color: blue;'>


  <div id='transhead' style='box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9); height: 100px; max-height: 100vh; overflow: hidden; position: fixed; top:0; left: 0; z-index: 10000;  width: 100%; '>
    <a href='/dxlphin/'>
      <div style='width: 100vw; height: 100%;  display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content:left'>
        <div class='revundhov' style='width: 5vw; height: 100%;'>HOME</div>
        <div class='revundhov' style=' width: 30vw; height: 100%;'>Products</div>
        <div class='revundhov' style=' width: 30vw; height: 100%;'>Ranges</div>
        <div class='revundhov' style=' width: 30vw; height: 100%;'>Featured</div>
        <div class='revundhov' style='width: 5vw; height: 100%;'>CART</div>
      </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you setting a style twice too .revundhov, all you have to do is remove `style='background-color: rgba(238, 236, 236, 0.9); width: 5vw; height: 100%;'` 
from .html and add it to your .css file

```
.revundhov:hover {
background-color: rgba(238, 236, 236, 0.4);
transition: background-color 0.3s ease-out;
-webkit-transition: background-color .3s;
-o-transition: background-color .3s;
}

.revundhov {
background-color: rgba(25, 31, 40, 0.9);
transition: background-color 0.2s ease-out;
-webkit-transition: background-color .2s;
-o-transition: background-color .2s;
background-color: rgba(238, 236, 236, 0.9); 
width: 5vw; 
height: 100%;
}   
<body style='background-color: blue;'>
<div id='transhead' style='box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9); height:     100px; max-height: 100vh; overflow: hidden; position: fixed; top:0; left: 0; z-index: 10000;  width: 100%; '>
<a href='/dxlphin/'>
  <div style='width: 100vw; height: 100%;  display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content:left'>
    <div class='revundhov'>HOME</div>
    <div class='revundhov'>Products</div>
    <div class='revundhov'>Ranges</div>
    <div class='revundhov'>Featured</div>
    <div class='revundhov'>CART</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you almost doing it right!

the only problem is, the inline css actually will also override ":hover" pseudo class.

so, there are two solutions for this problem;

1. you can remove the inline css (like my snipset below)

OR

2. you can simply add "!important" to your properties at ":hover" pseudo class.

the 2nd solutions is not recommend. so hopefully you will stick with the 1st solutions (check my snipset)

have a nice day!

```css
.revundhov:hover {
  background-color: rgba(238, 236, 236, 0.4);
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .3s;
  -o-transition: background-color .3s;
}

.revundhov {
  background-color: rgba(25, 31, 40, 0.9);
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s;
  -o-transition: background-color .2s;
}
```

```html
<body style='background-color: blue;'>


  <div id='transhead' style='box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9); height: 100px; max-height: 100vh; overflow: hidden; position: fixed; top:0; left: 0; z-index: 10000;  width: 100%; '>
    <a href='/dxlphin/'>
      <div style='width: 100vw; height: 100%;  display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content:left'>
        <div class='revundhov' style='width: 30vw; height: 100%;'>HOME</div>
        <div class='revundhov' style='width: 30vw; height: 100%;'>Products</div>
        <div class='revundhov' style='width: 30vw; height: 100%;'>Ranges</div>
        <div class='revundhov' style='width: 30vw; height: 100%;'>Featured</div>
        <div class='revundhov' style='width: 30vw; height: 100%;'>CART</div>
      </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: What does your answer add that hasn't been provided by @Daniel

Comment: im sorry, im new to this.. when i open this page, no one answer the question yet. then i open new tab and go to js fidle to test the code. 10 to 12 minutes later, i back to this tab without reload the page and post my answer. should i remove my answer?

Comment: You could still change the answer and explain why it is better

Comment: thanks a lot, your suggestion is really meaningfull.. i've edited my answer, hopefully the answer will have more meaning to the question..

Answer (score 0):

To completely remove inline style you can take a look at the following:

```css
.revundhov:hover {
  background-color: rgba(238, 236, 236, 0.4);
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .3s;
  -o-transition: background-color .3s;
}

.revundhov {
  background-color: rgba(25, 31, 40, 0.9);
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s;
  -o-transition: background-color .2s;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30vw;
}

.revundhov:first-of-type, .revundhov:last-of-type {
  width: 5vw;
}

body {
  background: blue;
}

#transhead {
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9); 
  height: 100px; 
  max-height: 100vh; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  position: fixed; 
  top:0; 
  left: 0; 
  z-index: 10000;  
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw; 
  height: 100%;  
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content:left
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id='transhead'>
    <a href='/dxlphin/'>
      <div class="container">
        <div class='revundhov'>HOME</div>
        <div class='revundhov'>Products</div>
        <div class='revundhov'>Ranges</div>
        <div class='revundhov'>Featured</div>
        <div class='revundhov'>CART</div>
      </div>
    </a><!-- FIX HTML markup -->
  </div>

</body>
```